justify-self no funciona en modo "auto" para los grid
Me he dado cuenta que el justify-self no funciona cuando al grid le aplico un auto para que ocupe el contenido necesario.
Me gustaría saber el motivo de este comportamiento o si en este caso hay que alinearlo de diferente manera.
En el siguiente ejemplo cuando le pongo
grid-template-columns: 150px auto auto;
justify-content: space-between;

No consigo forzar el alineamiento de un elemento hijo
justify-self: start;

Actúa como si el justify-content tuviera prevalencia.


.grid-1, .grid-2 {
    display: grid;
    background-color: tomato;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
}

.grid-1 {
    grid-template-columns: 150px auto auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.grid-2 {
    grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr auto;
}

.el1 {
    background-color: aqua;
}
.el3 {
    background-color: fuchsia;
}

.el2 {
    background-color: lime;
    justify-self: start; /* no se aplica en el primer grid*/
    text-align: left;
}
<div class="grid-1">
    <div class="el1">gr-temp-col:150px auto auto</div>
    <div class="el2">justify-self:start; no funciona </div>
    <div class="el3">Elemento 3</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="grid-2">
    <div class="el1">gr-temp-col:150px 1fr auto</div>
    <div class="el2">funciona sin necesidad de just-self </div>
    <div class="el3">Elemento 3</div>
</div>




Dices no funciona como me gustaría y no explicas como te gustaría

@Yussef Creía que el el código quedaba explicado.
Me refería que cuando el grid le pongo un auto en las columns y un space-between el justify-self de los elementos hijos no funcionan.
En este caso no se alinea a la izquierda de su propio contenido.

Quizás te estoy entendiendo mal, tú dices que el texto quede centrado?

@Yussef no entiendo porque cuando el grid tiene un auto y un space-between, el justify-self del elemento hijo no prevalece.
En el grid 1 se ve el comportamiento que no entiendo, ya que coge el espacio necesario (grid-template-columns: 150px auto auto), pero no alinea (justify-self: start).
Busco una explicación de porque no prevalece el justify-self tanto izquierda ni derecha

He aclarado un poco el código para que se entienda mejor

Creo que ahora entiendo. justify-content: space-between; y justify-self: start; son excluyentes (por decirlo de alguna manera) y tal como tú señalas el primero tiene prevalencia.  No es posible dejar un espacio entre items y a su vez decirle a un item que no deje espacio a la izquierda (de ahí que señalo que son excluyente). No tiene que ver con el auto si al 2do grid le colocas grid-template-columns: 150px auto auto; pasará lo mismo

No te respondo formalmente, porque no tengo explicación para el asunto de la prevalencia. Lo que si te puedo comentar es que todos estos comportamientos de layout flexibles tienen un comportamiento llamado fallback alignment que sucede cuando no es posible aplicar el comportamiento seteado y es porque dada su naturaleza se espera que existan estos casos https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align/#terms
